# Linux Server reboots unreasonably

Tags: linux, opensuse, meltdown, spectre

After applying Meltdown and Specter fix for Linux my **openSUSE Leap 42.3** server began to reboot unreasonably. It can work 1 day and then reboot or it can work for 15 mins after the last restart and then reboot again.

This is the list of patches:

```
openSUSE-2018-1
openSUSE-2018-118
openSUSE-2018-2
openSUSE-2018-75
openSUSE-2018-8
```

Could you please show the instructions how to remove them?

What can be a reason for this and how to fix it?

Comment: He spectre fixes released by Intel have been shown to be buggy and cause reboots. Revert the fixes related to spectre.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please show how to revert these fixes?